# How to use ngnix to route requests to different docker containers?

Tags: docker, nginx, containers

I have two containers -

1. Named abc running on port 3000
2. Named xyz running on port 5000

I have nginx running on my host. I want that when I type -

domain.com/abc/ --- it should go to abc:3000
domain.com/xyz/ --- it should go to xyz:5000

How to go about this?

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this. I am guessing it's too easy for them. Yet the post remains without a workable solution. Lol

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using ingress then you can use 

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dspace
  namespace: testing
spec:
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
http:
  paths:
  - path: /abc
    backend:
      serviceName: myapp
      servicePort: 3000
  - path: /xyz
    backend:
      serviceName: myapp
      servicePort: 5000
```

Comment: Strange thing is I can curl to http://localhost:3000 and http://abc:3000 but when used inside the nginx conf it doesnt go

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs correction, your routes are exactly the same. Anyways, you can configure the default.conf file in nginx :

```
upstream server1{
  server 172.17.0.4:80;
}
upstream server2{
  server 172.17.0.4:90;
}

server {
  listen 8001;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://server1;
  }

  location /static/ {
        proxy_pass http://server2;
  }
}
```

If you want to use names of the container :

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;   // < -- Name of container defined in DOCKER COMPOSE
}

upstream api {
    server api:5000;   // < -- Name of container defined in DOCKER COMPOSE
}

server{
    listen 80;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    }
    
    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
    
    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed the IPs keep changing everytime the containers are built and go up. Is there a solution where I can use the names given to the containers?

Comment: The js files paths are not being changed. I have a react application on port 5000. It tries to find domain.com/main.js where it should be domain.com:5000/main.js